# Porque meu aplicativo não está compatível com alguns dispositivos no Google play?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play

Eu postei um app no google play, mas infelizmente ele não está disponível para alguns dos meus dispositivos.
Estou muito confuso, pois no desenvolvimento com Eclipse, eu usei os mesmos dispositivos para testes e funcionam perfeitamente.
Será que falta alguma configuração para que fiquem compatíveis no Google play?

Meu Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mgoficina"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.NovaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.FormBuscaActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SearchActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SingleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SingleActivityEdit"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.ListaTrabalhosActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lista_trabalhos"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.NovaOsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nova_os"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.FechaLoteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fechar_lote"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.DefinicoesActivity"
        android:label="@string/definicoes"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.ExportaService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_INICIAR_EXPORTACAO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.FechaLoteService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_FECHAR_LOTE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.BackupService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_RESPOSTA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.UserActivity"
        android:label="@string/dados_usuario"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.RecuperaDadosActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_recupera_dados"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.PerfilActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.mgoficina.DeletaService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MGO_DELETA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.BemVindoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.SobreActivity"
        android:label="@string/sobre"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.ClientesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clientes"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.CameraActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_camera" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mgoficina.ServidorActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_servidor" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Que tipo de dispositivo? Seria um tablet? Além disso, aparece algum aviso na sessão de **OPTIMIZATION TIPS**? No upload, chegou a ver se tinha alguma opção para excluir dispositivos?

Comment: No meu caso @Wakim, são Smartfones, e na dica aparece "Projete seu app para tablets" e no upload tinha sim opção para excluir, mas não excluir nenhum. Será que é porque estou usando o SDK 2.3?

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos se ao menos você postar o seu "manifest"? Talvez ajude

Comment: Ok @GuilhermeNascimento vou atualizar a minha pergunta, obrigado!

Comment: Eu sei que é um chute meu apenas, mas aqui `<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />` você colocou como não requerido, mas aqui provavelmente é requerido
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />` acredito que talvez a propriedade `android:required="false"` deveria ser setada em todos relacionados a câmera. É apenas um chute

Comment: Meu amigo @GuilhermeNascimento primeiramente, isso não é chute, mas sim uma dica e toda dica é muito bem vinda. E que te dizer que com esse "chute", foram adicionados 2066 dispositivos. Muito obrigado Cara, acho que o caminho é esse. Considero essa resposta como válida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando nesta o recurso de câmera como não requerido:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />`

Porém recurso de focar a camera não foi definido como `false`,  provavelmente o GooglePlay assume como `true`, nesta linha:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`

É provável que ambos devem possuir `android:required="false"`:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Gracias. Resolveu meu problema.